# speech_recognition does not work with .pyw files

Tags: python, speech-recognition, google-speech-api

I'm creating a voice assistant with a graphical interface, I use `speech_recognition` to capture audio and recognize it into text, but if I use my script with the `.py` extension it works, instead if I use `.pyw` it doesn't work

I have searched a lot but can't find an answer to this problem

**I don't get any errors if I use `.py`**, so I don't understand why it doesn't work

```
import speech_recognition as sr
from speech_recognition import Microphone


device_index = 1
sample_rate = 48000
chunk_size = 1024
r = sr.Recognizer()




while True:
      with Microphone(device_index=device_index, sample_rate=sample_rate, chunk_size=chunk_size) as source:
           r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source, duration=0.7)
           r.pause_threshold = 400
        
           try:
               audio = r.listen(source,timeout=None,phrase_time_limit=5)


               Input = str(r.recognize_google(audio,language="it-IT",pfilter=0,show_all=False,with_confidence=False)).lower()

               with open("Inputs.txt", 'a') as fp:
                    fp.write(Input)

           except Exception as e:
               r = sr.Recognizer()
```

Comment: "it doesn't work" isn't very helpful.  What doesn't work?  You're using a relative path for the file name, so if you double-click the icon, you don't necessarily know where it's going to write that file.

Comment: when I use the r.listen function, with the .py extension I get a string which is then written to the file, instead when I use .pyw nothing is written to the file (I have tried both types of path, that's not the problem i think)

Comment: this is an example, in the real script, the string is saved in a variable, I save it to a file just to understand where the problem is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
audio = r.listen(source,timeout=None,phrase_time_limit=5)
data = r.recognize_google(audio,language="it-IT",pfilter=0,show_all=True,with_confidence=True)
```

I found a solution to the problem, i dont know why but if **show_all = False**, it works only with **.py**, instead if **show_all = True** it also works with **.pyw**

```
Input = (data['alternative'][0]['transcript']).lower()
confidence = (data['alternative'][0]['confidence'])
```